# TypeScript: Type '{ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have function like this:

```js
const createRelationship = <T extends { id: string }>(
  includedItems: Array<DataResponse<T>>,
  categories: Array<{ id: string, type: string }>,
): Array<T> => {
  return categories.map(({ id }) =>
    includedItems.find((includedItem) => includedItem.id === id) as DataResponse<T>)
  .map(flatAttributes);
};
```

It takes generic type T. First argument is Array of DataResponse where:

```js
interface DataResponse<T extends { id: string }, R = void> {
  id: string;
  attributes: Omit<T, 'id'>;
}
```

and:

```js
type Omit<A extends object, K extends keyof A> = Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, K>>;
```

so

```
type Example = DataResponse<{ id: string, key: number }> // { id: string, attributes: { key: number } };
```

Function `flatAttributes` looks like this:

```js
const flatAttributes = <T extends { id: string, attributes: any }>(item: T): { id: string } & T['attributes'] =>
  ({...item.attributes, ...item });
```

So it's kind of reverse operation, e.g.:

```js
flatAttributes{ id: string, attributes: { key: number } }) === { id: string, key: number }
```

Now to the point: Compilation of `createRelationship` thorws:

```
Type '({ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>)[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
  Type '{ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Where `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>'` is `Omit<T, 'key'>` and `Omit<T, 'key'> & {key: string}` should be the same `T`.

Any ideas how to declare this function without unsafe mapping? And why TypeScript behave like this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Omit%3CA%20extends%20object%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20A%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CA%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20A%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DataResponse%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20R%20%3D%20void%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20attributes%3A%20Omit%3CT%2C%20'id'%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20flatAttributes%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20id%3A%20string%2C%20attributes%3A%20any%20%7D%3E(item%3A%20T)%3A%20%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%20%26%20T%5B'attributes'%5D%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20(%7B...item.attributes%2C%20...item%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createRelationship%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%3E(%0D%0A%20%20includedItems%3A%20Array%3CDataResponse%3CT%3E%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20categories%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20id%3A%20string%2C%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%2C%0D%0A)%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20categories.map((%7B%20id%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20includedItems.find((includedItem)%20%3D%3E%20includedItem.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20id)%20as%20DataResponse%3CT%3E)%0D%0A%20%20.map(flatAttributes)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: I'd recommend you just use a type assertion if the compiler complains but you believe that what you're doing is safe.  That's what type assertions are for.  (Note that you should pay careful attention before using an assertion to make sure that is really *is* safe.  For example, if `T` is `{id: "stringLiteralValue"}`, then `T` is assignable to `{id: string}` *but not vice versa*.  Only you know if you care about those edge cases, though.)

Comment: Yes, after adding `as Array<T>` after return compilation error disappear. But why TS thinks that `Omit<T, 'key'> & {key: string}` is not exactly the same as `T`. Especially `id` attribute must exist in `T` type

Comment: Do you know about [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types)?  As I said, when `T` is `{id: "stringLiteralValue"}`,  `T` is assignable to `{id: string}` but `{id: string}` is not assignable to `T`.  They are not the same type.

Comment: Even when two types are exactly equal, it's still possible that the compiler might not recognize it because either: the analysis required to figure it out requires the intelligence level of a human being, which is still unfortunately lacking in the TS compiler as of v3.4; or the analysis is straightforward but doing it all the time would be too expensive and slow down the compiler too much to be worth it.

Comment: Yes, i know them and i understand why i was allow to do `as Array<T>` (thanks!). But i'm sill wondering why TS didn't calculate new type. Especially that Omit<T, 'id'> had to be calculated and `&` operator is pretty easy to calculate.